# How to flip image in matlab without using built in functions?

Tags: image, matlab, grayscale, flip

Write a MATLAB code that reads a gray scale image and generates the flipped image of original image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDbkF.png)
i am trying this code but is not giving me correct flipped image.Help will be much appreciated.Thankyou

```
clear all
clc
a=imread('pout.tif');
[r,c]=size(a);
for i=r:-1:1
  k=1;
for j=1:1:c 
    temp=a(k,j);
    result(k,j)=a(i,j);
    result(i,j)=temp;
     k=k+1;
  end
end
 subplot(1,2,1), imshow(a)
 subplot(1,2,2),imshow(result)
```

Comment: is this a homework problem? I don't understand why you can't use built in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing with indices is kind of unclear. You should also pre-allocate memory for the result.

```
clear all
clc
a=imread('pout.tif');
[r,c]=size(a);
result = a; % preallocate memory for result
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        result(r-i+1,j)=a(i,j);
    end
end
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(a)
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic indexing to flip a matrix. 2D case (gray-scale image):

```
a = a(:,end:-1:1); % horizontal flip
a = a(end:-1:1,:); % vertical flip
a = a(end:-1:1,end:-1:1); % flip both: 180 degree rotation
```

For the 3D case (color image) add a 3rd index `:`:

```
a = a(:,end:-1:1,:); % horizontal flip
```